# Why is filecmp.cmp being inconsistent?

Tags: python, windows, file, compare

This question is about the [`filecmp` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html) in Python 2.7.1. As far as I can tell, these two calls are identical (Windows, so case differences shouldn't matter). One returns `True` while the other returns `False`.

```
>>> filecmp.cmp(r'h:\dcim\112_1029\imgp7258.dng', r'd:\pictures\2016\112_1029\imgp7258.dng', False)
True
>>> filecmp.cmp('h:\\dcim\\112_1029\\IMGP7258.DNG', 'd:\\pictures\\2016\\112_1029\\IMGP7258.DNG', False)
False
```

`h:` is a SD card while `d:` is a standard hard drive. I've copied the file from `h:` to `d:` through Explorer, so they *should* be identical. I even did it again just to be sure. The results of each call are consistent no matter how many times I do them or what order I do them in.

Here's a little more experimentation just to confuse things further.

```
>>> f1 = r'h:\dcim\112_1029\imgp7258.dng'
>>> f2 = r'd:\pictures\2016\112_1029\imgp7258.dng'
>>> f3 = 'h:\\dcim\\112_1029\\IMGP7258.DNG'
>>> f4 = 'd:\\pictures\\2016\\112_1029\\IMGP7258.DNG'
>>> f1.upper()==f3.upper()
True
>>> f2.upper()==f4.upper()
True
>>> filecmp.cmp(f1, f2, False)
True
>>> filecmp.cmp(f3, f4, False)
False
>>> filecmp.cmp(f1, f4, False)
True
>>> filecmp.cmp(f3, f2, False)
True
```

As requested in a comment, here are the results of `os.stat` for each of the 4 filenames. You can see that they are identical except for the access and creation times, but those times are consistent for each version of the filename.

```
>>> os.stat(f1)
nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=15112724L, st_atime=1490418000L, st_mtime=1477766688L, st_ctime=1477766686L)
>>> os.stat(f2)
nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=15112724L, st_atime=1490488519L, st_mtime=1477766688L, st_ctime=1490488519L)
>>> os.stat(f3)
nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=15112724L, st_atime=1490418000L, st_mtime=1477766688L, st_ctime=1477766686L)
>>> os.stat(f4)
nt.stat_result(st_mode=33206, st_ino=0L, st_dev=0, st_nlink=0, st_uid=0, st_gid=0, st_size=15112724L, st_atime=1490488519L, st_mtime=1477766688L, st_ctime=1490488519L)
```

An additional test I thought of:

```
>>> def hashfile(filename):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        m.update(f.read())
    return ''.join('%02x' % ord(b) for b in m.digest())

>>> hashfile(f1)
'a0042d8623567bcf429069d17e7c3148'
>>> hashfile(f2)
'a0042d8623567bcf429069d17e7c3148'
>>> hashfile(f3)
'a0042d8623567bcf429069d17e7c3148'
>>> hashfile(f4)
'a0042d8623567bcf429069d17e7c3148'
>>> filecmp.cmp(f1, f2, False)
True
>>> filecmp.cmp(f3, f4, False)
False
```

Comment: I've tried your code with both Python 2.7 and 3.6 on both Windows and Linux, and I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Vallentin it probably has something to do with the filesystem on the SD card, but I'm truly mystified at the possible cause. I assure you it's real.

Comment: Which type of SD card are you using? and which file system is it using?

Comment: @Vallentin or perhaps it has something to do with the way Windows caches files. `f3` and `f4` would be exact matches for the filenames that Explorer used to copy the files, the others differ by case.

Comment: @Vallentin it's a Lexar 32GB SDHC card formatted as FAT32.

Comment: Could you try `print(os.stat(f1))` for `f1, f2, f3, f4` and add the output to the question?

Comment: That's weird. `filecmp` uses `(stat.S_IFMT(st.st_mode), st.st_size, st.st_mtime)` as the file signature, so this is impossible. I also tried using an SD card as well as a USB. Tried both between NTFS and FAT32 (assumed this could be the cause). Sadly I'm still unable to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is this all in a single process, or have you restarted Python? A non-shallow file comparison caches the outcome based on the filenames and a subset of the stat info: `stat.S_IFMT(st.st_mode), st.st_size, st.st_mtime`. Check `filecmp._cache`.

Comment: I think it's a bug that this cache isn't case-insensitive on Windows, and specifically using the same APIs that Windows itself uses to upper-case-normalize strings, which differs significantly from what Python does.

Comment: @eryksun it caches the results? Why would it do that? Any way to turn it off? That appears to be the problem, restarting Python fixed it.

Comment: @eryksun sure enough, it says so right in the documentation. If you want to turn that into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation for 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2/library/filecmp.html) does not mention it, but the [documentation for 3.4](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/filecmp.html) contains this very important note:

> This function uses a cache for past comparisons and the results, with cache entries invalidated if the os.stat() information for the file changes. The entire cache may be cleared using clear_cache().

The cache appears to be case sensitive on the filename.

In my case I had re-copied the file, so the `os.stat()` information did not change (Windows preserves these attributes). However when I tested with the filename in a different case, I got the un-cached result which was *different* than the cached result.

Calling `clear_cache()` as advised in the documentation was the exact solution for my problem.

Comment: Oof. I've spent days researching the exact same problem to finally find this. For those of us stuck on 2.7 due to other constraints, is there a solution besides clear_cache()? My current fallback is to either use a time delay before checking, or just compare hashes and call it good.